# How does a 'combined tolerance' affect multiple dice rolls?

Tags: probability

This is from a pen and paper like game scenario. Imagine it like this:

You stand in front of a gap and try to jump over it. We try to calculate the chance that your jump is successful.

1. For your jump, 3 of your attributes are taken into consideration and tested individually. Lets call them 'power', 'dexterity' and 'stamina'.
2. For each of your 3 relevant attributes listed above, you roll a 20-sided dice - let's call this an attribute trial. Each of the trials needs to be successful individually to successfully make the jump. In order for a roll to be successful, it must be equal or lower than your attribute. Example: if your power is 13, you need to roll a 13 or lower to succeed your power trial.

So far the formula to successfully make the jump would look like this:

$$
\frac{POWER}{20} * \frac{DEXTERITY}{20} * \frac{STAMINA}{20}
$$

Essentially you would have to win your power trial, your dexterity trial and your stamina trial individually. If each of your attributes were 13, you would have a success chance of

$$
\frac{13}{20} * \frac{13}{20} * \frac{13}{20} = 27.46\%
$$

This is the correct result if we have a 'jumping' skill of 0. However, now we need to also take into account your jumping skill:

3. You also have talent points specifically for 'jumping'. These are a 'tolerance' that you may use up over all of your 3 rolls as needed. For example, if you have 6 talent points in jumping, you have a combined tolerance of 6 for all of your attribute trials. If you roll a 15 for power, it eats up 2 of your combined tolerance, because you are 2 away from your power roll requirement of '13 or lower'. This would leave you with a remaining tolerance of 4 for the remaining 2 attribute trials.

How would the jumping skill affect the formula above? Would it be save to take the average tolerance per roll and add it to each single attribute trial, like this?

$$
\frac{POWER + \frac{JUMPING}{3}}{20} * \frac{DEXTERITY + \frac{JUMPING}{3}}{20} * \frac{STAMINA + \frac{JUMPING}{3}}{20}
$$

If we had a jumping skill of 6, that would essentially make it

$$
\frac{13 + 2}{20} * \frac{13 + 2}{20} * \frac{13 + 2}{20} = 42.18\%
$$

Is it really as simple as this, or is it more complicated than simply averaging the jumping value per roll?

Comment: Is your problem:  "What is the probability you roll three 20-sided dice and have the sum below 40"?

Comment: No, it's not about a sum. It's about some kind of pen and paper game mechanic. You need all of your 3 dice rolls to individually succeed, however you are granted a 'combined tolerance' from your skill points over all 3 of your dice rolls. That combined tolerance is to make your skill points significantly influence your ability to succeed in a given action.

Comment: Please specify your criteria in unequivocal mathematical terms.  No "...it's about some kind of..."  As a sanity check, please give an example of three outcomes that you would accept that do *not* conform to my criterion ($<40)$.

Comment: If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Why $40$?  Do you mean $45$? $(3\cdot13+6)$   Rolling $15$ three times is acceptable.  Rolling $20$ then two $1$'s is not acceptable, though it sums to only $22$.

Comment: Huh???  You allow a... "'combined tolerance' of 6 for all throws combined."  So why can't I "use up" all my tolerance on a single roll?  I fear that this kind of nipping and tucking will go on until you, once and for all, write a crisp, clean, and unambiguous mathematical equation stating what *is* and *is not* acceptable.

Comment: Thank you two for your feedback. I have overhauled the question completely to make proper use of math formatting and being more precise with my problem. Please have another look at it.

Comment: It looks like you basically allocate talent points after seeing the result of the die roll. Is that correct? If so, for a quick-and-dirty estimate I think a weighted average of the talent points should work pretty well. An exact value will require more intricate computation.

Comment: @amd Yes, you first roll the dice and then use as much tolerance from the talent points as you need and can. Without having to go full detail, how would you calculate more exact results?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I thought saulspatz's explanation captured the rule clearly as did the original post: a set of rolls containing a $20$ is not acceptable since $20$ exceeds $13$ by $7$, which is greater than the tolerance of $6$. The general rule is that you have a credit of $6$. If a roll exceeds $13$ by some amount, you use up that amount of credit. But you don't get any credit back for rolling less than $13$. So you can't simply consider the total of the rolls. If after three rolls your credit is negative, you've failed. Anything else counts as success.

Comment: I don't know whether you noticed this question in the "Related" sidebar, but it is very similar to your problem, except for some extra conditions involving rolls of $1$ and $20$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750301/probability-of-3-20-sided-dice-throws-penpaper?rq=1.  It has one answer, which seems to ignore the extra conditions, but which also seems to modify the problem in other ways before answering it. Its approach is rather different from mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be treated as a Markov chain with a set of eight states, $\{-,0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, where the state "$-$" indicates that the total excess of the rolls so far that exceed $13$ is greater than $6$, while the numerical state labels are simply the amount of unused tolerance.  With the rows and columns indexed by the state labels in the order listed above, the transition matrix is
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{7}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{6}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{5}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{4}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{3}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0 & 0\\
\frac{2}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0\\
\frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20}\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The success probability you are looking for is the complement of the probability in the lower left corner of the matrix $T^3$.  This matrix element represents the probability, given that the initial state is "$6$", that after three rolls the state is "$-$".  Its complement is the probability that the tolerance has not been exceeded.

To compute the needed matrix element, it is not necessary to compute the whole matrix $T^3$; you only need to compute $r_6Tc_-$, where $r_6$ is the last row of $T$ and $c_-$ is the first column of $T$.  So
$$
\begin{aligned}
r_6T&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{7}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{6}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{5}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{4}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{3}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0 & 0\\
\frac{2}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20} & 0\\
\frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{20} & \frac{13}{20}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{60}{400} & \frac{31}{400} & \frac{30}{400} & \frac{29}{400} & \frac{28}{400} & \frac{27}{400} & \frac{26}{400} & \frac{169}{400}\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
r_6Tc_-&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{60}{400} & \frac{31}{400} & \frac{30}{400} & \frac{29}{400} & \frac{28}{400} & \frac{27}{400} & \frac{26}{400} & \frac{169}{400}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ \frac{7}{20}\\ \frac{6}{20}\\ \frac{5}{20}\\ \frac{4}{20}\\ \frac{3}{20}\\ \frac{2}{20}\\ \frac{1}{20}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2156}{8000}\end{bmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Numerically, $\frac{2156}{8000}=0.2695$.  The complement of this is $1-0.2695=73.05\%$, which is considerably higher than your estimate.

To generalize, let $d$ be the number of sides on the die, $a$ the attribute, $t$ the tolerance, and $n$ the number of rolls.  Assume that $a+t\le d$.  The Markov chain will have a set of $t+2$ states, $\{-,0,1,\ldots,t\}$, and the transition matrix will be
$$
T=\frac{a-1}{d}I+\frac{1}{d}L+V,
$$
where $I$ is the $(t+2)\times(t+2)$ identity matrix, $L$ is the lower triangular matrix with all elements above the diagonal equal to $0$ and all elements on or below the diagonal equal to $1$, and $V$ is the matrix with all elements $0$ except for column $1$, where the element in row $i$, for $1\le i\le t+2$, is $\frac{d-a-i+1}{d}$.  The probability of success is the complement of the element in the last row and first column of $T^n$.

If $a+t>d$, the matrix will be slightly more complicated.

**Added in response to request in comments for further explanation:** Looking at $T^1$ first, the element in row $i$, column $j$ is the probability of going from state $i$ to state $j$ in one roll. Example: the number in the fourth row, first column is $\frac{5}{20}$. In our labeling this means going from state "$2$" to state "$-$", and $\frac{5}{20}$ is correct since if $2$ units of tolerance remain, five outcomes of the roll, namely $16$, $17$, $18$, $19$, $20$, use up more than $2$ units of tolerance. Notice that every row of $T$ sums to $1$ since the probabilities of all possible states must total $100\%$.

Analogous properties hold for higher powers of $T$, such as $T^3$. Row $i$, column $j$ of $T^3$ is the probability of going from state $i$ to state $j$ in three rolls, and elements in row $i$ of $T^3$ sum to $1$. Our interest is in the seven three-step transitions $6\to6,\ 6\to5,\ \ldots,\ 6\to0$ since these are the outcomes in which one starts with $6$ units of tolerance and uses anywhere between $0$ and $6$ units of tolerance in the three rolls. It is less work to look only at $6\to−$ and subtract from $1$.

The probability of $6\to−$ in three rolls is the number in the last row, first column of $T^3$. We don't need to compute all $36$ elements of $T^3$ just to read off one of them. Focusing only on the one we need, instead of computing $T\cdot T\cdot T$, we take only the row we need from the first factor of $T$ and only the column we need from the last factor of $T$. This is how we get $r_6\cdot T\cdot c_-$, which gives $26.95\%$ with complement $73.05\%$.  Note that the analogous probability for one roll is $1-\frac{1}{20}=95\%$, while the analogous number for two rolls is $1-\frac{60}{400}=85\%$.

To answer your second question, you could indeed use a different transition matrix for each roll if the attribute changed from roll to roll.

If you are uncomfortable with matrices, note that anything you can do with matrices you can also do, less efficiently, with a probability tree. I say "less efficiently" because the growth in the number of branches of the tree is exponential in the number of rolls. For this problem, each node in the tree will have eight offspring, so the fan-out is prodigious.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Unfortunatelly I need to take a step back to learn more about matrix calculations in order to be able to fully understand everything that goes on here. But it's super interesting and helping me out a bunch with my inner math enthusiast :)

Comment: If I understand it correctly the 73.05% you get there the result for ONE of the attribute trials (e.g. one roll), is it? You mention T³ somewhere, but then decide that you only need r_6Tc. Wouldn't you need to use r_6T³c there in order to account all 3 rolls though?

Comment: What if the attributes power, dexterity and stamina are different values? Would you then use `T_power * T_dexterity * T_stamina` instead of `T³`?